# How to get all possible combinations of each element in a 2D-array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array
`int[][] lists=new int[][]{{22, 23},{34, 35},{47, 15}};`

I have to get all combinations of each elements in every rows, like this:
`int [][] result= {{22,34,47},{22,34,15},{22,35,47},{22,35,15},{23,34,47},{23,34,15},{23,35,47},{23,35,15}}`

Then for each rows from the newest array I have to calculate average. For this I create a method `average(int[]a)`.
All I need is to get only those combinations with highest average.
Because my initial array can have a large number of rows/columns, I'm trying to generate each combination and check if it's average is higher then memorate it.
Here is my code, but obviously it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

```
public static int average(int[]a) 
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)sum+=a[i];
    return sum/a.length;
}
public static void cartesian(int[][] lists, int[] values, int n) 
{
   int sum=0;
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   if (n == lists.length) {
    if(average(values)>sum) {
       result.clear();
        result.add(Arrays.stream(values).boxed().collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()));
      sum=average(values);}
  }
  else 
   {
      for(int i: lists[n]) {
       values[n] = i;
       cartesian(lists, values, n+1);
    }
   }
return result;
}
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      List<List<Integer>> result = cartesian(lists, new int[lists.length], 0);
      for(List<Integer> i: result)  System.out.println(i);
     }
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) has a combinations function that may be useful for this. Not sure if it does arrays though, maybe only nCr type.

Answer (score -1):

I think there are a couple errors of logic in your `cartesian` code. From what I can tell, that is the function that determines what array has the highest average. First of all, in the statement

```
int sum=0;
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   if (n == lists.length) {
    if(average(values)>sum) {
```

The last line is irrelevant - you've defined `sum` so that if your values aren't negative the if statement will always be true. Also, later in the code,

```
else 
   {
      for(int i: lists[n]) {
       values[n] = i;
       cartesian(lists, values, n+1);
    }
```

I think you meant to put `cartesian(lists, values, n+1)` outside of the for loop. Here is how I would rewrite this code:

```
public static void cartesian(int[][] lists, int[] values, int n) 
{
   int sum=0;
   List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
   int[] totest = lists[n];
   if(average(totest) > average(values) || r.equals(null)) {
       result.clear();
       result.add(Arrays.stream(totest).boxed().collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList()));
      if(n != lists.length - 1){cartesian(lists, totest, n + 1)};
}
  else 
   {
       if(n != lists.length - 1){cartesian(lists, totest, n + 1)};
   }
return result;
}
```

Comment: I tried your cod and I get an error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at  `int[] totest = lists[n];`

Comment: Sorry, the problem was also that I didn't add the if statement to recursively call the function in the `else` part.

Comment: My biggest concern here is that you've somehow preserved the `return` statement.